# How can I remedy sticky latex paint without stripping?

Tags: wood

I have an old, probably 50+yrs, architecture drawing table that I've resized and using as kitchen island. I need it white, so I lightly sanded old top and painted with latex. I allowed drying time between layers (2), but it's lightly sticky. Is there remedy without stripping off?

Comment: How long has it been drying?

Comment: How long has it been? Was the first coat fully dry when you applied the 2nd, have you tried having a fan blow across the area or at least move the air around.

Comment: If youre in the US west, and you want  a durable finish for that table, talk to TAP Plastics.

Answer (score 1):

Note that plain Latex is a poor choice for a table top, it is not very durable. As Ed noted, there are enamel latex paints, hopefully you used one of these.

Nevertheless, it should dry eventually. You can speed it up by putting it in a well ventilated area. Or better yet, heat it slightly by putting it outside in the sun for an afternoon.

Comment: Depends on the type of latex there are latex enamel paints that are very tough. But I agree with ventilation.

Answer (score 0):

There are latex paints that are more like old-school enamel in terms of durability, but I have experience with latex wall paint on furniture. It's not often a good outcome. Even if it cures past the tacky stage it's going to be soft. Wall paint is designed to cover well and be easy to work with, mostly.

One idea is to **coat the paint with a furniture protectant**--something like a wax or polish. I don't have a particular product in mind, but I've heard of such a thing. It might save you some hassle.